# select2 not working on already "selected" options

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

Am using `select2` plugin for selecting multiple countries. 
When I populate the options for the `<select>`, for certain `<option>` I used the `selected` attribute to pre-select it.

Code (options were echoed using PHP in the page):

```
<select name="allowed_countries[]" class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" required>
  <option value="ALL"  >All Countries</option>
  <option selected value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="AL">Albania</option>
  <option selected value="DZ">Algeria</option>
  <option value="DS">American Samoa</option>
  <option value="AD">Andorra</option>
  <option value="AO">Angola</option>
  <option selected value="AI">Anguilla</option>
  <option value="AQ">Antarctica</option>
  <option selected value="AG">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
  <option value="AR">Argentina</option>
  <option value="AM">Armenia</option>
  <option value="AW">Aruba</option>
  <option selected value="AU">Australia</option>
  <option value="AT">Austria</option>
  ....
</select>
```

At footer of the page, I am calling the function:

```
<script>    

    $(document).ready(function(){

        $(".select2").select2();

    });

</script>
```

It displays the `selected` items properly. 
[image]

But if I try to add/delete an item, all the selected items except the first one gets removed! 
[image]
And you can see from the screenshot that, the selected options are not shown in grey background like the "Afghanistan" !

Any idea on what's causing the issue?

---

**EDIT (SOLVED)**

After several attempts of debugging, found that the issue was with another line on that page: `$(":input").inputmask();` This selector seems to be causing the conflict. I just removed that selector with specific class name of the element which I was using the inputmask for and the select2 seems to be working fine now!

Thanks to all who tried to help me. I appreciate it.

Comment: what version of select2?

Comment: @DanielH its 4.0.3

Comment: use select chosen instead

Comment: could you inspect the html after the selected options are unselected?

Comment: Thanks guys. After several attempts of debugging, found that the issue was with another line on that page: `$(":input").inputmask();` This selector seems to be causing the conflict. I just removed that selector with specific class name of the element which I was using the inputmask for and the select2 seems to be working fine now!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function () {
    $('.select2')
        .select2({
            width: 500
        })
        .on('change', function(){
            console.log( $(this).val() );
        });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://select2.github.io/dist/js/select2.full.js"></script>
<link href="https://select2.github.io/dist/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<select name="allowed_countries[]" class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" required>
  <option value="ALL"  >All Countries</option>
  <option selected value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
  <option value="AL">Albania</option>
  <option selected value="DZ">Algeria</option>
  <option value="DS">American Samoa</option>
  <option value="AD">Andorra</option>
  <option value="AO">Angola</option>
  <option selected value="AI">Anguilla</option>
  <option value="AQ">Antarctica</option>
  <option selected value="AG">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
  <option value="AR">Argentina</option>
  <option value="AM">Armenia</option>
  <option value="AW">Aruba</option>
  <option selected value="AU">Australia</option>
</select>
```

Comment: seems fine to me?

Comment: Thanks. After several attempts of debugging, found that the issue was with another line on that page: `$(":input").inputmask();` This selector seems to be causing the conflict. I just removed that selector with specific class name of the element which I was using the inputmask for and the `select2` seems to be working fine now!